# Outlook 2013 Keeps Checking Deleted Account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm using a POP server with Outlook 2013 desktop. I deleted an account on the server and within Outlook but it keeps checking for mail from the deleted account. The strange thing is the account is not listed in the Outlook email account lists (File | Account Settings | Email tab). I've re-added the account to Outlook and the server, sent an email fine and then removed it again from both places yet Outlook keeps checking for it and prompting for credentials. I run ESet as a virus protection which has an Outlook plug in and have tried disabling that to no avail. All apps are up to date. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, your profile may be corrupted, please try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: That was the problem.  I had to create a new profile and add all the accounts back in.  I wish there was a "duplicate" link for an email account in the setup.  Thanks for the help.